# Angular 6 Application hosted in AWS EC2 instance not reachable using public IP

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2

I am facing issues while accessing an Angular 6 application using public IP through internet.
What I did was, I started a windows EC2 instance. After that installed nodejs and angular cli as below-

npm install -g @angular/cli

Then created a new angular application as below

ng new my-app

After starting the angular application my-app with the below command

ng serve   //Configured port 80

I can access this within the windows EC2 instance and my browser in EC2 instance  shows the angular application up and running however, I am not able to access from outside i.e from my local machine browser. If I put the public IP address in browser I cannot access.Though the port 80 is set as inbound rules but still it says

**This site can’t be reached
ec2-13-233-140-16.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com refused to connect.**

I am doing this in Mumbai region so latency should not be the issue.

I tried this with Ubuntu instance still the same problem.

Need some valuable suggestion.

Thanks

Sachin

Comment: Ping public IP first. Make sure it did go through. Then check your firewall setting of inbound traffic.

Comment: If you connect to the EC2 instance, are you able to access the application on `ec2-13-233-140-16.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com` from that machine, or only on `localhost`?

Comment: Ok. So you mean to say the inbound rules in security group? I did some troubleshooting. I installed apache server on the same EC2 instance and able to access it on port 80.Then I disabled the apache server and started my angular application and starts on port 80 ,but don't see it running if I open it in browser.So if apache server has no issues being accessed by public IP then what is blocking the angular application to be accessed by Public IP.

Comment: Not able to access via ec2-13-233-140-16.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com or the IP address but  can browse it inside the EC2 instance using localhost.

Comment: What command are you using to serve the angular application?

Comment: I am using npm start.  My package.json has the line    "start": "ng serve --port 80",

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the following command

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80
```

This will ensure that it listens on addresses other than localhost

Comment: Ok I tried this way also used the command ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 in my package.json but all I can see is the angular application running and accessible from within the EC2 instance but not outside of the EC2 instance i.e when I try to access it from local machine via it's public IP.My inbound rules defined in security group are as follows HTTP    TCP   80     0.0.0.0/0.Is there anything more I need to do.

Comment: If you connect to the EC2 instance again, can the EC2 instance connect using a) the private IP, and b) the public IP? Or will it still only find it on localhost?

Comment: Ok If I understood your question correctly this is what I see after connecting to the EC2 instance.After connecting into the windows instance remotely I start my angular application and in browser If I launch localhost:80 , I see my application up and running. With the public IP if I do it in another browser I get Connection has timed out. With private IP If I browse it in browser I get Unable to Connect. So altogether it works with localhost only inside the EC2 instance and neither with private and public IP .

Comment: Okay, what about if you try `--host 0.0.0.0` but instead of `0.0.0.0` you use the private IP?

Comment: I logged into my EC2 instance and  replaced 0.0.0.0 with the private IP and started the angular application.After this what I see that now with localhost it does not work but with private IP is does work . And with public IP it gets timed out.

Comment: Okay, in that case just switch the private IP with the public IP in that command and you should be able to connect using that.

Comment: Switched the private IP in the command and started .It is accessible from within the instance via private IP but not from outside of instance via the public IP.

Comment: Is it accessible using the public IP from within the instance?

Comment: No not accessible via public IP from within the instance and also from outside the instance.

Comment: Ok now I am able to make it work but with a Ubuntu instance.What I did was create an Ubuntu instance in Mumbai region and created a new application with command ng new my-app and then started the server with the command ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 and I am able to browse my application with the public IP on port 80 and also tried with 4200 port and works. Not sure why it was not working with windows instance .I still don't have an answer to it but with Ubuntu it works ! Yes it works. I am glad that it works. Will try to work with windows instance but thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok now I am able to make it work but with a Ubuntu instance.What I did was create an Ubuntu instance in Mumbai region and created a new application with command ng new my-app and then started the server with the command ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 and I am able to browse my application with the public IP on port 80 and also tried with 4200 port and works. Not sure why it was not working with windows instance .I still don't have an answer to it but with Ubuntu it works ! Yes it works. I am glad that it works. Will try to work with windows instance. Would also like to say thanks a lot to every one for their help.